# Google Chrome search field does not provide same options than

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine

I am Chrome Web browser user, I have noticed that when I search using the all-in-one text field of Chrome, the results or the occurrences does not provide the same set of options when I search using the classic www.google.com's search text field. In the last case, I can see the '+1' button beside on each occurrence, on the first, I can not.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome's Omnibox displays a mixture of:

- Pages from your browsing history
- Your bookmarks
- Google search suggestions
- Domain/website suggestions

For the search and domain suggestions, Chrome sends your Omnibox input to
`http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&hl=en-US&q=YOURQUERY`
(or similar URL, depending on your locale; there may also be other subdomains that get used, I'm not sure)
and this returns a simple JSON result, which Chrome interprets and then displays the results below the Omnibox, (possibly) along with items from your local history and/or bookmarks.
These results are fairly simplistic, as they are not HTML, and are displayed as part of the browser's interface.

When going to http://www.google.com and using Google's normal webpage search, it queries `http://www.google.com/s?...` with a long string of user-specific parameters (assuming Instant is On).

As Google.com is a webpage, it can easily display lots of HTML, and that's where all the +1 buttons, magnifying glasses and various little links get displayed.

Chrome's Omnibox just gives you a simplified version with a handful of links, which you can then click on and get taken to the rich Google.com webpage.

There's also another server that is used solely for search suggestions (JSON format again): `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?json&q=YOURQUERY`
This uses the [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) standard, which is used in other softwares; eg Firefox uses this URL with its search box, as does my [Fauxbar](http://www.fauxbar.org/) extension for Chrome.

If your Omnibox suggestions differ from what appears on Google's website, each search URL might be using different algorithms. I haven't really looked into how each search URL differs with their results. Only Google will really know.

If you wanted to display the Google.com webpage's search results as you type, you could enable Chrome's Instant feature. (search for it in Chrome's options)